# JTidy preserve CSS rules

Tags: java, html, css, jtidy

Looking for a way to take some html like:

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        *.td {
         font-weight: bold;
        } 
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div>blah blah blah</div>
     </body>
  </html>
```

And run it through JTidy, and keep the CSS rule in the output of the parser.

The  tag is gone in the final output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the word2000 flag set on JTidy.  That is stripping the style tags.

Answer (score 0):

That's not HTML. It is a mixture of CSS and HTML. You can't expect an HTML processor to understand it the way you do.

Comment: Yeah, I had oversimplified the example - should be more clear now.

Comment: It's still not HTML. <style> is required to have a *type* attribute.

Comment: That's what I get for typing examples in manually.  JTidy inserts the type attr.  It was the word2000 flag in JTidy stripping the style tag.  Thanks for your attention.